# NSDocumentController openDocument: panel no longer permits access to app iCloud container in OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: macos, cocoa, icloud, osx-elcapitan

I have an OS X/iOS App that uses the old style ubiquitous container id *TEAMID.com.companyname.product*, and is built using `NSDocument` on OS X and `UIDocument` on iOS.

File opening has been working fine on OS X 10.8, 10.9 and 10.10 using the built in `NSDocumentController openDocument:` panel. In 10.10 this panel was extended by Apple to permit iCloud Drive access. At the top of the panel the selector titled “iCloud Library” shows “Appname - iCloud” and “iCloud Drive” as options.
Selecting the former gives access to documents in the App ubiquity container, and the later shows available iCloud Drive folders.

In 10.11 El Capitan, selecting “Appname - iCloud” - the view doesn’t change (you see the top level view of iCloud Drive Folders). There is no warning message. Selecting the Appname under iCloud in the sidebar has the same result.

Given the nature of the application (the data is private and isn’t designed to be read by any other application) it isn’t ideal to make the ubiquity folder public - so I would prefer not to go down that path.

A work around is to search for the appropriate file type (kind) in the request panel and select Search: This Mac - this works fine, as do saved URLs from previous opens. So App sandboxing isn’t causing the problem.

Obviously I would like the 10.10 behaviour to continue - but it isn't obvious how to achieve this or if it is a bug. It may be that Apple assume all apps built using NSDocument would wish to make their App containers public.

Comment: I can confirm that adding the appropriate NSUbiquitousContainers keys to the app plist on iOS and setting NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic to true (and bumping CFBundleVersion) immediately makes the container visible both on iOS and OS X. Unfortunately this is not what I want. :-(

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that this issue is a bug in OS X 10.11, and the standard `NSDocument` file open/save/move panel fails to be coerced into the old behaviour. However a reasonably simple solution is to provide two new application menu items:

- **Open iCloud** listing all available documents in the (private) ubiquity container,
- **Move to iCloud** using `[NSDocument moveDocumentToUbiquityContainer:]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the apps iCloud container Public by adding the following to your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HHWT75NS6T.au.com.ossh.appName</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>None</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan I'm aware of the above. Trouble is this makes your ubiquity container public. In the case of my app, it isn't appropriate to make it public (and makes no sense as the file format isn't public either). There has been a change of behaviour of the file requestor which will break any similar app that doesn't wish to make the app ubiquity container public.

Comment: Well Public means the another App like Finder or ICloud Drive can see its contents. This means you can copy files to and from the container in the usual Finder manner. Many apps have proprietary formats so as long as you use an appropriate document type definition this should not be a problem. Of course I don't really understand your use cases but the only alternative would be to write your own File Manager.

Comment: BTW I don't believe this is a bug as I logged a bug for this some time ago and it was closed - 'working as designed'.